# How add attribute to Sphinx index from scheme?

Tags: php, sphinx

I use PHP XMLWriter:

```
$xmlwriter->startElement('sphinx:schema');

   $xmlwriter->startElement('spinx:attribute');
     $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("name", "path");
     $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("type", "string");
   $xmlwriter->endElement(); // attr

   $xmlwriter->startElement('sphinx:field');
      $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("name", "content");
   $xmlwriter->endElement(); // field

$xmlwriter->endElement(); // schema

$xmlwriter->startElement('sphinx:document');
   $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("id", 1);
   $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("path", "TEST_ATTRIBUTE");
   $xmlwriter->startElement("content");
      $xmlwriter->text("TEST_CONTENT");
   $xmlwriter->endElement(); // field
$xmlwriter->endElement(); // doc
$xmlwriter->endElement(); // docset
```

So I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sphinx:docset>
  <sphinx:schema>
    <spinx:attribute name="path" type="string"/>  - why there is '/>' not '>'?
    <sphinx:field name="content"/>
  </sphinx:schema>

  <sphinx:document id="1" path="TEST_ATTRIBUTE">
    <content>TEST_CONTENT</content>
  </sphinx:document>
</sphinx:docset>
```

So I try: indexer --rotate --all --config /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
using config file 'sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'test1'...

WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo

So I don't get atribute in index.

Comment: And how is your XML writer code looks like?

Comment: Shouldnt it the very least be `->writeAttribute("type", "string");` but also read the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-attribute.php

Comment: thanks barryhunter! sorry I tried correct my question a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo...

```
$xmlwriter->startElement('spinx:attribute');
                      -----^
```

> why there is '/>' not '>'?

https://www.google.com/search?q=XML+closing+tags

> Each tag opened has to be closed. XML is pedantic about this. However,
>   if a tag is empty (no content), a single tag can serve as both the
>   opening and closing tag if it ends with /> rather than with > . XML -
>   Libxml2 http://www.xmlsoft.org/XMLinfo.html

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct code!!!

```
$xmlwriter = new xmlWriter();
$xmlwriter->openMemory();
$xmlwriter->setIndent(true);
$xmlwriter->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$xmlwriter->startElement('sphinx:docset');

$xmlwriter->startElement('sphinx:schema');

$xmlwriter->startElement('sphinx:field');
   $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("name", "content");
$xmlwriter->endElement(); // field

$xmlwriter->startElement('sphinx:attr');
  $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("name", "path");
  $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("type", "string");
$xmlwriter->endElement(); // attr

$xmlwriter->endElement(); // schema

$xmlwriter->startElement('sphinx:document');
    $xmlwriter->writeAttribute("id", 1);

  $xmlwriter->startElement("content");
    $xmlwriter->text("TEST_CONTENT2");
  $xmlwriter->endElement(); // field

  $xmlwriter->startElement("path");
    $xmlwriter->text("TEST_ATTRIBUTE2");
 $xmlwriter->endElement(); // field

$xmlwriter->endElement(); // doc

$xmlwriter->endElement(); // docset
print $xmlwriter->outputMemory(true);
```